# cakephp find('list') - problem using

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get an array to poplulate a Counties select. If I use find('all') I can get the data but this array needs flattening to use in the view with $form->input($counties).

If I use find('list') I can't seem to get the right array - which is simple array of county names.

What I have tried is this:

```
        $ops=array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'display' => '!=0',
            'TO_DAYS(event_finish) >= TO_DAYS(NOW())'
        ),
        'fields' => 'DISTINCT venue_county',
        'order' => 'venue_county DESC'
    );
    $this->set('counties', $this->Event->find('list',$ops));
```

but the SQL this generates is:

SELECT `Event`.`id`, DISTINCT `Event`.`venue_county` FROM `events` AS `Event` WHERE `display` = 1 AND TO_DAYS(event_finish) >= TO_DAYS(NOW()) ORDER BY `venue_county` DESC

which generates an error because it first inserts the `Event`.`id` field in the query - which is not wanted and causes the error.

In my database I have a single table for Events which includes the venue address and I don't really want to create another table for address.

What options should I be using efor the find('list') call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 'list' expect 2 fields - one for the ID and another for the Text label. If you use only one it get current Model ID for the IF field. Here is how it should look like:

```
$ops=array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'display !=' => 0,
        'TO_DAYS(event_finish) >= TO_DAYS(NOW())'
    ),
    'fields' => array('venue_county', 'venue_county'),
    'order' => 'venue_county DESC',
    'group'=>'venue_county'

);
$this->set('counties', $this->Event->find('list',$ops));
```

Bear in mind that conditions like ">", "!=", "LIKE", "IN" etc are placed from the left side (like in my example the **display** field).

Basically you can change the fields but first one need to be the ID one the next one need to be the TEXT one

Comment: What if I want to put an option not from database, such as "Please Select" as the default selection?

Answer (score 1):

try specifying the fields for the list

```
<?php
$this->set('counties', $this->Event->find('list',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array('display' => 0),
        'TO_DAYS(event_finish) >= TO_DAYS(NOW())'
    ),
    'fields' => array('Event.venue_county','Event.venue_county'),
    'order' => 'venue_county DESC'
)));
?>
```

though I might recommend you do your date conditions natively (assuming that the [event_finish] field is a data or datetime field). and while you're at it you might as well simplify the display field condition to an IS vs. and ISN'T (I'd recommend making that field a type tinyint(1) so it's basically true/false).

```
<?php
$this->set('counties', $this->Event->find('list',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'display' => 1,
        'Event.event_finish >' => date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),
    ),
    'fields' => array('Event.venue_county','Event.venue_county'),
    'order' => 'venue_county DESC'
)));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples - and thanks for extra tips - I'll take all I can get :-)

Comment: I notice that the SQL for this automatically includes GROUP BY without having to specify this condition (I added DISTINCT in my original code). That's good but a little scary as I don't know under what cirumstances it adds it. Do you know what rule it is using or which other cirumstances it is added?

Comment: Review: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data

As for the group by automatically - I haven't noticed that, it could be because the two fields are the same, so that it doesn't have to return more rows than it needs to, but I haven't really looked into it, nor have I found any problems with the find(list)... works well for me.

You might add <code>"recursive' => -1</code> to the find options in case there are other linked models you want to ensure are excluded.

Comment: Thanks for the recursive tip - yes I thought the same regarding two fields.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
$ops=array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'display' => '!=0',
        'TO_DAYS(event_finish) >= TO_DAYS(NOW())'
    ),
    'fields' => array('id','venue_county'),
    'order' => 'venue_county DESC'
);
$this->set('counties', $this->Event->find('list',$ops));
```